# Are nocte and noctu interchangeable?

Tags: vocabulary, grammar-choice, time

The regular ablative of *nox* is *nocte*.
At least in the temporal sense *noctu* is a synonym of *nocte*.
Are *nocte* and *noctu* fully interchangeable as temporal expressions?
In particular, can I attach adjectives or pronouns to *noctu* the way I can with *nocte*?
For example, I can say *quadam nocte* or *nocte atra et procellosa*, but I don't know whether I can use *noctu* in such a way.

Answer (score 5):

**Adverbs** are not normally modified by adjectives. And **'noctu,'** occurs mostly in Livy, usually on its own, but sometimes modified by the adverb: secretly  **'clam.'** And occasionally  with **numquam, fere, saepe, diu.** (never, almost, often, for some time.)

But the ablative '**nocte**,' in an adverbial phrase can have an adjective. The phrase '**sub nocte**' in  the descent to the underworld 'Lonely, at nightfal, they went unseen through the shadow,' has a transferred epithet, and adverbial phrase.

> Ibant obscuri sola sub nocte per umbram.

Adjectives qualifying 'nocte' : **proxima nocte,** 'next night,' and Adverbs qualifying the complete averbial phrase are found: **fere nocte, clam nocte**  'almost by night,' 'secretly by night.'

Comment: This answer is incorrect as it stands: there is no gaping chasm between adverbs and nouns, and many adverbs come from ablative forms. In this case, L&S [explicitly states](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/morph?l=noctu&la=la&can=noctu0&d=Perseus:text:1999.04.0059:entry=noctu&i=1#lexicon) (see I.β) that *noctu* is ablative and gives many examples of it being modified by adjectives like *hac* and *concubia* or even participles, like *noctu futura*.

Comment: @brianpck, do you want to add that as an answer? That *noctu* is considered a real ablative and in particular that it can be modified by ablatives like *futura*, *hac* or *tertia* would make a good answer. I can do that myself if you prefer, but I want to give you the opportunity. There is no hurry. (I didn't notice your comment until now.)